# How to concert a hexadecimal expression to string?

Tags: c#, hex, ascii

I am trying to convert some data in hexadecimal into string using this code:

```
hex = hex.Replace("0x", "");
hex = hex.Trim();

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i += 2)
{ 
    string hs = hex.Substring(i, 2);
    stringBuilder.Append(Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(hs,16)));            
}
```

Hex being in the format "0x53 0x50 0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34 0x35 0x36".

However, I keep getting an error

> System.FormatException: 'Could not find any recognizable digits'

Hope to understand what is the issue and how to resolve it. Many thanks!

Comment: So, you have `"0x53 0x50 0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34 0x35 0x36"` string and you want to obtain what kind of result (`int`, some other `string`)?

Comment: Are you looking for `SP123456` as the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you right, you want to turn each encoding like `0x53` into corresponding `char` (`S`). If it's your case we can *query* the `source` string with a help of *Linq* and combine the result back into string with a help of `string.Concat`:

```
using System.Linq;

string source = "0x53 0x50 0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34 0x35 0x36";

// SP123456
string result = string.Concat(source
  .Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Select(item => (char)int.Parse(item.Substring(item.IndexOf('x') + 1), 
                                  NumberStyles.HexNumber)));
```

Yet another possibility is *Regular Expressions*:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string source = "0x53 0x50 0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34 0x35 0x36";

var result = Regex.Replace(
  source, 
@"\s*0x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}\s*", 
  m => ((char)Convert.ToInt32(m.Value.Trim(), 16)).ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for not being clear with my question but yes. I want to convert the hexdecimal expression to "SP123456" form. Your solution works too and i am able to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Like so?

```
var input  = "0x53 0x50 0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34 0x35 0x36";

var result = input.Split(" ").Select(item => (char)Convert.ToInt32(item, 16)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to use `Convert.FromHexString`, after stripping out the  `0x`

```cs
var hex = "0x53 0x50 0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34 0x35 0x36";
var span = hex.Replace(" 0x", "").Substring(2);
var bytes = Convert.FromHexString(span);
var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JNaAtq)